# Excel Auto fit using CSV C#

Tags: c#, excel, csv

this is the code i just want to know how to auto fit i try the
   Excel.Rows.AutoFit but tells me error and this Excel.Columns.AutoFit

```
private void exportToExcelToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Excel Documents (*.xls)|*.xls";
        sfd.FileName = "export.xls";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //ToCsV(dataGridView1, @"c:\export.xls");
            ToCsV(dataGridView1, sfd.FileName); 
        }  
    }
    private void ToCsV(DataGridView dGV, string filename)
    {

        string stOutput = "";
        string sHeaders = "";

        for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Columns.Count; j++)
            sHeaders = sHeaders.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Columns[j].HeaderText) + "\t";
        stOutput += sHeaders + "\r\n";


        for (int i = 0; i < dGV.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            string stLine = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                stLine = stLine.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\t";
            stOutput += stLine + "\r\n";
        }

        Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
        byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(stOutput);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        bw.Write(output, 0, output.Length); 
        bw.Flush();
        bw.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
```

please help me to autofit the column thanks !

Comment: If I understand you right you want to set the column-widthj of every columns accordingly to its max content in csv, is this right? But this is not possible because CSV has no such style-options, its simple text seperated by colons. Furthermore: what exact error do you get?

Comment: no error thank you for the comment sir. what do you think is better CSV or Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?

Comment: CSV for the win. Can be edited both in text editors and specialized editors like Excel. Formatting remains an option for the user. You will thank yourself later for using CSV when you have to open the file in another application or even using another programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, you don't really save the data in XLS format but the resulting file will have `xls` extension. No wonder if Excel shows a warning when you open the file because it detects that something's wrong with the format.
Because the file is nothing more than text, it does not store information about data format, column widths, font styles, etc.

If you really need formatting you can use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` as you mentioned or some other library like [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to create real xls(x) files.

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file with XLS extension is not a real Excel file. It is just a CSV and MS Excel knows to open the CSV and displays its data inside a sheet. An XLS file is a binary file, not a text file like CSV.

To create real XLS file, you can use an Excel library like [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com) for example and, to be more specific, this [C# Excel library](http://www.easyxls.com/net-excel-library) from all their Excel libraries.

For exporting the DataGridView to Excel, check this [code sample](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/FAQ/export-datagridview-to-excel.html). The rows and columns will be automatically fit to content.

Comment: i see is EastXLS is free?